# MySQL Recommendation Engine Query

Tags: mysql, recommendation-engine

I'm trying to write a very basic recommedation/upselling query, where I can return a list of products that other people have purchased that have been in the same "order" as a product the current user has purchased, but aren't the same product.

I simple way to explain this is:

- User A buys a spanner and a drill
- User B buys a drill and some screws
- User C buys some nails and a spanner

So I'd like to recommend screws and nails to User A.

I have a products table, a Invoice_Header table, and an Invoice_Line table.

What I have so far is this (which probably explains my requirements a little better).

```
SELECT
    Products.Product_Code,
    Products.Full_Description,
    count(Products.id) as hits
FROM
    Products as Products,
    Invoice_Header as Invoice_Header,
    Invoice_Line as Invoice_Line,
    Invoice_Line as Invoice_Line_Common,
    Invoice_Line as Invoice_Line_Products
WHERE
    Invoice_Header.account_number = 765
    AND
    Invoice_Line.invoice_num = Invoice_Header.invoice_number
    AND
    Invoice_Line_Common.product_code = Invoice_Line.product_code
    AND
    Invoice_Line_Products.invoice_num = Invoice_Line_Common.invoice_num
    AND
    Products.Product_Code = Invoice_Line_Products.product_code
    AND
    Products.Product_Code != Invoice_Line.product_code
group by Products.Product_Code
order by hits
limit 0,10
```

Now, this runs like a dog, as I have 800,000 Invoice Lines.

Has anyone any recommendations for doing this faster?

Comment: Are you indexing the searched columns?

Comment: looks like you are doing a equi join. try joining on primary key field. also, if you have mysql GUI browser then use the query analyzer and see which part of the query is more expensive.

Comment: Yes the searched columns are all indexed. I'm quite sure that the above query isn't optimal - I'm just using it to easily explain the data I'm trying to get.